# FIX QuoteRequest parsed by Fiximulator

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj, quickfixn

I'm sending a message to FIXimulator and it recieves it:
[image: FIXimulator raw message as recived]

But it seems Fiximulatro when parsing a RequestMeassage ommits group content (55=AMZN^38=100) :
[image: FIXimulator parsed message]

As for some reason, server misses group content, that has been within the incoming mesage, it responds with Unsupported type message back. (obviously, if group is empty once parsed by FIXimulator) .

It looks to me that the message that have been sent to server is correct. However, still there is some issue with the server not parsing it properly.

Any ideas and suggestions what is wrong with my FIX string=request or it is genue defect with FIXimulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be any issue with your message, it is just that FIXimulator does not handle 35=R messages; this is why you are getting the "Unsupported type" error.
Furthermore, although your message has been correctly processed by QuickFixJ, the "message details" window does not seem to properly handle repeating group, whence the missing tag 55 and 38.